# SEF URLs Joomla 3

Tags: joomla3.0, sef

Hi I have a Joomla3 site that has a main menu with a root item "products."  The sef url "sitename/products" works great.  However, I also want to have an sef url for sitename/products/productmodel1 that is not displayed in the menu.  If I try to create a products/productmodel1 menu tree in a second "phantom" menu that isn't displayed anywhere, I can't create a duplicate root alias for "products."   Is there any workaround so I can either set up the phantom menu with the same root aliases as the main menu, or hide the menu items in the main menu so the sef links work but the menu items are not displayed?  I tried adding System Link/Menu item aliases to the phantom menu, but it is still using the system generated aliases to create the sef urls.

Answer (score 0):

When I have problem like you have now I do solve it like this:

- I do create in back-end menu called `Addresses`
- Then create item called `Products` (You can just copy your Products item) in `Addresses` menu
- Then make an alias in your main menu (this one displayed on site) to `Products` menu item from `Addresses`
- Now add product sub-menu item into `Products` item from `Addresses` menu for every product you want to have this nice SEF url

Its fastest way to make it. There is also harder way but makes whole job automatic (good if you have 100+ products and plan to insert much more). It requires to recreate router for your products catalogue and possibly.